# Can we pass parameter to C# property?

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, parameters

We have properties for a class which has getter - returns the value

Ex:

```
Public Employee Department
{
get { return GetTheValue("Mid Level") ;} 
}
```

GetTheValue is our framework method which takes parameter value and returns string.  The Parameter vlaue is hard coded now which we want to make that dynamic... We want to pass that Parameter Value directly to Property. Can we pass parameter to property ? Don't want to make that as method, looking to pass parameter to property only.. how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can do it like an indexer, but that is going to confuse anybody who trys to maintain your code. Just make it a method.

Comment: Why would you *not* want to make it a method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* use an [*indexer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) which resembles a property...

```
public Employee this[string department]
{
    get
    {
        return GetTheValue(department);
    }
}
...

var instance = new Whatever();
var employee = instance["Mid Level"]
```

but that is **abuse**. I would just use a method instead...

```
public Employee GetDepartment(string department)
{
    return GetTheValue(department);
}
```

Comment: I have MULTIPLE properties, if I change them to indexers, how can I call them from instance object..  instance[" ???"]

Comment: You can only have one indexer per type.

Comment: You can't, thats why you should **not** be using indexers for this!

Comment: Actually, what I said is not _totally_ true. I just checked [the spec'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691131(v=VS.71).aspx) and you can have multiple indexers so long as they differ in signature but this is very limiting and just an all round _bad_ idea.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this suggestion will lead to a lot of confusion around what is possible and what should be done. I feel this site is best when the responses attempt to answer the question with the best solution to the problem instead of saying, "This is what you are asking for, but don't do it."

Comment: @WilliamCustode I can appreciate that and I took your feedback on board.

Comment: I think it was good to show that the desired behaviour is possible but should not be used. Developers often get an idea in their head and will be determined to make it happen that way. To be shown that it is possible but should not be done will likely get the reader off of that track of thought faster.

Comment: @Petrichor, thank you,...I will see if I  can use indexer because I have multiple properties... but just curious to know why it's abuse to use indexer  ?

Comment: @msbyuva because indexers imply a collection, like an array. A method should be a method and a property should be a property, don't shoe-horn one into another just because you can, it makes for ugly, hard-to-maintain, and even harder to understand code. The next developer is going to come in and think "WTF was this last guy thinking?" And redo your code the right way, breaking lots of good design rules and possibly breaking your API.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing perfectly describes the purpose of a method. You are looking to do this:

```
public Employee GetDepartment(string value)
{
    return GetTheValue(value);
}
```

Because what you're asking is to add a parameter to a property, and a property simply is syntactic sugar for two methods, `get_xxx` and `set_xxx` where optimizations can be made regarding the calling convention. As such, properties were designed to not be ideal for what you are doing.

Comment: (I come in peace). I am not going to down-vote your answer like you did mine but **to be fair**  this does _not_ answer the question. I totally appreciate the point you made in your comment but it is _possible_ that this question is hypothetical and for education purposes. In the (admittedly) likely case that it is not, the best we can do is warn against this approach. The asker is likely to find indexers to be too limited for his/her purposes _anyway_ based on the comment he/she left on my answer.